# Undefined method songs

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to submit songs to a particular event, and the only thing that is stopping me is an error message. I have gotten this to work when a user has events, but not when a event has songs. Here is what my code looks like:

Event model:

```
class Event < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :songs, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Song model:

```
class Song < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :event
  validates :artist, presence: true
  validates :title,  presence: true
end
```

Events controller

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

    def show
        @event = Event.find(params[:id])
        @songs = @event.songs.paginate(page: params[:page])
    end

    def create
        @event = current_user.events.build(event_params)
        if @event.save
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            redirect_to root_url
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private 
      def event_params
        params.require(:event).permit(:name, :code)
      end
end
```

Song controller

```
class SongsController < ApplicationController

    def create
        @song = current_event.songs.build(song_params)
        if @song.save
            flash[:success] = "Song Created"
            redirect_to root_url
        else
            render 'users/show'
        end
    end

    def destroy
    end

    private
      def song_params
        params.require(:song).permit(:artist, :title)
      end

end
```

sessions_helper.rb

```
module SessionsHelper

  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end
  def current_event
    @current_event ||= Event.find_by(id: session[:event_id])
  end

  # Returns true if the user is logged in, false otherwise.
  def logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def log_out
    session.delete(:user_id)
    @current_user = nil
  end

end
```

Any help on this would be fantastic!

Comment: Which line is your error on

Comment: The first line in the create method in the SongsController

Comment: How is `current_event` defined? Are you sure it is an `Event` object?

Comment: I will update my code so it shows were the current_event method is being defined

Comment: should I have created the current event inside of my event_helper.rb file instead of putting it in with my session_helper.rb file?

Comment: Can you please post the exact error message you're getting. Are you including the `SessionsHelper` in `SongsController`?

Comment: I am not including the SessionsHelper in the SongsController. The exact error message reads as follows: NoMethodError in SongsController#create undefined method 'songs' for nil:NilClass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current_event method is looking for a session to get the event_id

```
  def current_event
    @current_event ||= Event.find_by(id: session[:event_id])
  end
```

But you are not setting a session for this.

You are on the user session:

```
  # Logs in the given user.
  def log_in(user)
    session[:user_id] = user.id
  end

  # Returns the current logged-in user (if any).
  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find_by(id: session[:user_id])
  end
```

The result being that `current_event` is likely not returning an event object (its nil) and therefore `.songs` is not a valid method to call on it.

So you need to either set a session with event_id or come at it a different way (not using sessions).

Hope it helps

Comment: how would I go about setting a session with an event_id?

Comment: You have done it for user. session[:event_id] = event.id

Comment: But you need to first set the event. what dictates the "current_event"?

Comment: What is controlling the current_event? I would assume controlling that would be the user. Based on a user they have certain events.

Comment: So each user has 1 event or many events? If many events, which of those events should rails know is the "current" one.

Comment: If each user only has one event then you can just do current_user.event

Comment: Ah Very well, thank you you were a tremendous help :)

Comment: Perhaps consider your database structure and ensure everything adds up before you do too much in rails otherwise you will have lots of code to re-write if you change your data structure later. Good luck.